# MessageBox.Show() causing WPF application to run?

Tags: c#, wpf

Inside the  `App.xaml.cs` of my WPF application, starting from the entry point `Main()` which simply looks like this:

```
[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
    var app = new App();
    app.StartApp();
}
```

I experience some unexpected behavior when either of the two MessageBox's are uncommented.

```
protected void StartApp()
{
    // uncomment this  = the messagebox will show and return after 'okay' is clicked.
    // The application will never start even after `this.Run()` is called?
    //MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    this.InitializeComponent(); //auto generated code
    this.StartupUri = new Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    // uncomment this = the messagebox will show and simultaneously the application will run().
    // The line below will only be hit on termination of the application
    //MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    this.Run();
}
```

At a guess, `MessageBox.Show` is doing something funky with the current Application context, as putting `MessageBox.Show` on the very first line of `Main()` works exactly as expected.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show()` enables the message pump, which after `InitializeComponent()` will cause your startup window to run.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Run()` besides WPF-specific stuff calls `Dispatcher.Run()`.
Last one runs a window message loop.
Same does native message box inside `MessageBox.Show`.

Hence message box calls before `Application.Run()` should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

`Task.Run(()=>MessageBox.Show("Hello")).Wait()` will produce the 'expected' result - i.e. it's message pump will not affect the execution of the calling Application.